# Ошибка при сборке драйвера WDM с помощью g++

Tags: g++, mingw, драйвер

Пишу драйвер на C, компилирую с помощью gcc, все работает. Но мне нужно перейти на c++, но с помощью g++ не компилируется. Ошибка в `ntddk.h`, а конкретнее в функции `InterlockedBitTestAndSet`. Но что именно не так и как исправить я не могу понять.

Сам файл драйвера **DriverMinGW.cpp**:

```
#include <ntddk.h>

extern "C" NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath);
VOID UnloadRoutine(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject);


extern "C" NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
  DriverObject->DriverUnload = UnloadRoutine;
  return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

VOID UnloadRoutine(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{

}
```

**makefile**:

```
OBJECTS = DriverMinGW.o
TARGET = DriverMinGW.sys
CFLAGS = -I D:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ddk -Wall -m64 -shared
CC = g++

all: $(TARGET)

clean:
    cmd //C del $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)

%.o: %.c clean
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -Wl,--subsystem,native \
    -Wl,--image-base,0x10000 \
    -Wl,--file-alignment,0x1000 \
    -Wl,--section-alignment,0x1000 \
    -Wl,--entry,DriverEntry@8 \
    -Wl,--stack,0x40000 \
    -Wl,--dynamicbase \
    -Wl,--nxcompat \
    -nostartfiles -nostdlib -o $(TARGET) \
    $(OBJECTS) -lntoskrnl -lhal
```

Сама ошибка:

```
D:\mingw64\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f makefile
D:\Project\DriverMinGW\DriverMinGW.o
g++ -I D:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ddk -Wall -m64 -shared -c DriverMinGW.c -o DriverMinGW.o 
In file included from D:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ddk/ntddk.h:38:0,
                 from DriverMinGW.c:1:
D:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ddk/wdm.h: In function 'BOOLEAN InterlockedBitTestAndSet(volatile LONG*, LONG)':
D:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ddk/wdm.h:205:1: error: 'BOOLEAN InterlockedBitTestAndSet(volatile LONG*, LONG)' redeclared inline without 'gnu_inline' attribute
 InterlockedBitTestAndSet(
 ^
In file included from d:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\intrin.h:41:0,
                 from D:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ddk/wdm.h:68,
                 from D:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ddk/ntddk.h:38,
                 from DriverMinGW.c:1:
d:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\psdk_inc\intrin-impl.h:800:1: error: 'unsigned char InterlockedBitTestAndSet(volatile long int*, long int)' previously defined here
 __buildbittesti(InterlockedBitTestAndSet, __LONG32, "lock bts", "I", volatile)
 ^
In file included from D:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ddk/ntddk.h:38:0,
                 from DriverMinGW.c:1:
D:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ddk/wdm.h: In function 'BOOLEAN InterlockedBitTestAndReset(volatile LONG*, LONG)':
D:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ddk/wdm.h:224:1: error: 'BOOLEAN InterlockedBitTestAndReset(volatile LONG*, LONG)' redeclared inline without 'gnu_inline' attribute
 InterlockedBitTestAndReset(
 ^
In file included from d:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\intrin.h:41:0,
                 from D:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ddk/wdm.h:68,
                 from D:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ddk/ntddk.h:38,
                 from DriverMinGW.c:1:
d:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\psdk_inc\intrin-impl.h:807:1: error: 'unsigned char InterlockedBitTestAndReset(volatile long int*, long int)' previously defined here
 __buildbittesti(InterlockedBitTestAndReset, __LONG32, "lock btr", "I", volatile)
 ^
make.exe": *** [DriverMinGW.o] Error 1
```